# How to init DB connection for ewery member of multiprocessing Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I use `multiporcessing.Pool` class for submitting tasks to workers, I want to each worker, when starts (or gets replaced thanks to `maxtasksperchild` parameter) to open its own DB connection.

now code looks similar to this:

```
conn = None
def init(dsn):
    global conn
    conn = connect(dsn)

def f(x):
    global conn
    <do the work with conn>

p = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=('dsn',), maxtasksperchild=100)
p.map(f, ....)
```

this works, but that `global` keyword looks extremely ugly, can it be done more gently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while with this problem... Simple answer is, you can't do this kind of things with current implementation of `Pool`